# How can I access an HTML !ENTITY from Python. Advice Please

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I have an HTML file which starts as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE gdml [
<!ENTITY sub2 SYSTEM "sub2.xml">
]>

<gdml xmlns:gdml="http://cern.ch/2001/Schemas/GDML"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema/gdml.xsd">
```

I would like to process the Entity in Python.

I have tried

```
# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

def preProcessHTML(filename) :
    # instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
    f = pythonopen(filename)
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(f.read())
```

But it just prints out

```
Import GDML file : /home/keith/GDML-Test-Files/GDML/entity2.gdml
Encountered some data  :


Encountered some data  :
]>


Encountered a start tag:gdml
Encountered some data  :
```

So I don't see how I access the actual data 
"!ENTITY sub2 SYSTEM" "sub2.xml">

Comment: Looking at the doc, have you considered adding `handle_decl` and/or `unknown_decl`?

Comment: Your doc is XML, not HTML.

Comment: Yes I know its a XML file, but I want to access the HTML Entity values before I process as an XML file

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks @shahkalpesh adding a

```
def handle_decl(self, decl):
    print "Encountered a declaration ", decl
```

Printed out the info I require. I can now add code to access and process